# Angular real time application development

Tags: angularjs

I have been developing an application that allows for multiple people to concurrently modify data and automatically propagate the changes real time. In the processes of doing so some questions about the nature of $watch arose.

One of them was:

***What happens if the data model being watched changes while the watch call is in process?***

From some experimental results I believe that the watch gets called again at the same time. I believe some infinite digest loops have been caused by this.

And another noteworthy question not about watch was:

***What is the best way to block the client to wait for a promise to be executed?***

Any resources on Angular RT Web development would be awesome too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you first question I suggest reading Angular's runtime concepts in the [developer guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts). Basically it is only natural that data might change while `$digest` phase in progress because multiple `$watchers` could modify it. The catch here is that angular expects the model to stabilize in 10 iterations or it will throw `Maximum iteration limit exceeded.` error, but you can increase this limit.

Now the second question is a bit of a oxymoron - the whole point of promises is **not** to block client while something is executed asynchronously. Usually you would do async action, get promise and hook up a callback to be executed after the async action is complete.

Comment: I know the second question seems weird. The issue arises from the act of generating promises inside a $watch call (since I need to async talk to a Firebase). I am afraid that when the first $watch call happens, Firebase queries will be started async and when the second one happens, all queries will incorrectly modify my shared data structures. The idea is that I do not block on querying the server but I block on receiving the data. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, but it will not be possible without hacking core of Angular to accept a promise as `$watcher's` return value and wait for it to complete. And it would be very, very inefficient. Your best bet would be building a service that would throttle these async calls into discrete (say, 20 ms) intervals and then update model with latest data. All in all, angular is not the best choise for this kind of interaction, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What would be your choice to write an application that needed such a high degree of concurrency?

Comment: I haven't got much expertise in RT apps to give good advice on best framework for this. I worked with Angular for some time now to see where it excels and where it's a pain to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Firebase and Angular fire?
http://angularfire.com/

I'm pretty new to this, but it seems like the best choice for real time apps atm.

Comment: I am using that. The issue has to do with a normalized database schema.